# Django Flatpages Using: Site matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I'm a noob at Django.

I've created a flatpages object in my admin console when I visit the url which I run on a local server, I get a "Site Matching query does not exist" error.
Can someone help me?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^home/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here's the error log:

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/flatpages/views.py" in flatpage
35.     site_id = get_current_site(request).id

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/sites/shortcuts.py" in get_current_site
15.         return Site.objects.get_current(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/sites/models.py" in get_current
67.             return self._get_site_by_request(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/sites/models.py" in _get_site_by_request
44.                 SITE_CACHE[host] = self.get(domain__iexact=host)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in get
385.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /default/
Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have not defined [SITE_ID](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-SITE_ID) in settings.